# h1 element distance to border differs at top and bottom

Tags: html, css, border

CSS:

```
h1 {
    width: 25%;
    margin: 11rem auto;

    font-family: 'Baron Neue';
    font-size: 4vw;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;

    border-top: solid 2px white;
    border-bottom: solid 2px white;
}
```

HTML:

```
<h1>POTJESMARKT</h1>
```

The h1 tag has `<body> </body>` as it's parent.

The problem is that the border on the top isn't attached to h1, while there's no padding there. What I would like eventually is about a 1rem padding between h1 and the border, at the top and bottom. I could solve this by adding padding at the bottom of h1, but if I then resize my browser window, the distance from h1 to border isn't equal anymore on top and bottom.

[image: h1 with borders]

[image: Chrome developer tools]

Comment: try adding `line-height`

Comment: still the same problem, the distance isn't equally spaced.

Comment: It could be your font that's causing the problem. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/t4ec0zb7/ - by me it's working fine

Comment: So if it's the font, there's not much really that can be done to solve the problem except for adding padding at the bottom i suppose..

Answer (score 0):

Solved it in an 'ugly' way:

I added `padding-bottom: 1vw;`

This way, the padding scales together with h1, which makes it acceptable.

Comment: will this padding not change on resizing the screen, though?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as (technically), it's *working* here:

```css
html,body{background:red;}
h1 {
    width: 25%;
    margin: 11rem auto;

    font-family: 'Baron Neue';
    font-size: 4vw;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;

    border-top: solid 2px white;
    border-bottom: solid 2px white;
}
```

```html
<h1>POTJESMARKT</h1>
```

In which since I haven't actually got your font style installed, I believe your problem is with the font itself. In order to 'fix' this you could;

- A: Find out the font's baseline margin (in px) and add the extra 'top' padding to your h1 element
- B: Use a different/more common font
- C: 'Guess' by adding some padding-bottom to your element.

---

Just some points I would like to note:

- Ensure you **import** your font (so that everyone can 'use' it (i.e. google fonts))
- I wouldn't really be that keen on using vw and vh unless *actually* needed
- Again, personal preference would stop me from using 'rem' values, and either stick to em, px, or otherwise.

Comment: See my own answer, I guessed the padding bottom at 1vw, and that seems to work.

Comment: @user3165926: hence I added other options, as well as some 'points to note' - I would be particularly interested if there was a 'pixel calculator' out there that would check your padding-top and padding-bottom's for a font out there to get an *accurate* padding correction.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a semantic answer:[Header fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s56r1qw7/)

**html:**

`<h1><strong>Potjes market</strong><h1>`

**css:**

```
h1 {
  font-size:4em;
  border:3px solid blacK;
}
h1 > strong {
  position:relative;
  bottom:0.1em;
}`
```

This pushes the text slightly up so that the border looks even above and below